# Index radio box and contained buttons

Tags: python, wxpython

I have multiple radio boxes containing three buttons as shown below. I want to keep track of clicked radio buttons within radio boxes then do some processing. I am not sure how to index radio box and then clicked radio buttons within that radio box as there are multiple boxes. Any suggestions?

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "test", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(900, 600))
        radio1Choices = ['F','G','P']
        # rb_list has 23 records -- basically used to set the distance b/w radio boxes
        for i in rb_list:
            self.radio1 = wx.RadioBox(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, (550,i), (20,5), radio1Choices, 3, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS | wx.NO_BORDER)
            self.radio1.SetSelection( 0 )
            grid_sizer.Add( self.radio1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        # Bind the radio box select event to a function
        self.radio1.Bind( wx.EVT_RADIOBOX, self.on_selected )

    def on_selected(self, event):
        if self.radio1.GetStringSelection() == 'F':
            print "F"
        elif self.radio1.GetStringSelection() == 'G':
            print "G"
        else:
            self.radio1.GetStringSelection() == 'P'
            print "P"
```

Answer (score 1):

append each radiobox into a list then only you can bind each radio box with its event

Try this code:

```
        self.radiobuttonlist=[]
        for i in range(0,len(lut_code)):
            rb += 40

            self.radiobuttonlist.append(wx.RadioBox(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, (550,rb), (30,5), radio1Choices, 3, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS | wx.NO_BORDER))
            self.radiobuttonlist[-1].SetSelection(0)
            print self.radiobuttonlist[-1].GetId()
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBOX,self.Getvalues,id=self.radiobuttonlist[-1].GetId())

            grid_sizer.Add(self.radiobuttonlist[-1], 0, wx.ALL, 5)
```

To get the selected radio-button value use:

event.GetEventObject().GetSelection()

Try this code:

```
def Getvalues(self,event):
        print event.GetEventObject().GetSelection()
```

Comment: This only specifies whether I clicked 'F', 'G', or 'P' in a radiobox. But I need index of that box as well.